# asp.net mvc, angular: Confirming addition of an entity after exception thrown

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Terrible post Title I think - My brain stopped working...

Here's the concept:
I have an application in which users can add a student to a class within a given school. A student has the properties: FirstName, LastName, Email, and Id.

Students can be in multiple classes. The first time a user enters a student, if he/she does not already exist, he/she is added. 
Users however, are prone to mistakes so in the event they enter an email address but misspell FirstName and LastName. If the email address entered already matches a student in the database but the FirstName and LastName is different, the user must confirm that the student in the system is what the user intended to enter.

I wrote it such that an exception is thrown and will ask the user to confirm adding the student in the system to a class.

My issue arises where I want to show different errors based on whether or not the error is a duplicate student in a class vs student being added to another class with matching email but different names.

**School.Data**

```
public class Student {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }

  public School School { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
 //api v1.0
[HttpPost]
[Route("{SchoolId:int}/members/{ClassId:int}/students")]
public ActionResult AddStudent(int SchoolId, int ClassId, Student Student) {
  try {
    var model = new ManageStudentsViewModel();        
    model.AddStudent(SchoolId, ClassId,Student);
  }
  catch (HttpException e) {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(e.GetHttpCode(), e.Message);
  }
  return Json(new {
    Success = true
  });
}
```

**View Model:**

```
    public void AddStudentAddStudent(int SchoolId, int ClassId, Student Student) {
  using (var db = new SchoolContext()) {
    var class = db.Schools.Find(SchoolId).Classes.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == ClassId);

    if (class.Students.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Email == Student.Email) != null) {
      var message =
        string.Format("A student with the email address {0} is already in this class", Student.Email);

    //TODO:should not throw an HttpException here. Write a custom exception handler then replace.
      throw new HttpException(409, message);
    }

    var existingStudent = db.Students.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Email == Student.Email);
    if (existingStudent != null) {
      if (existingStudent.FirstName == Student.FirstName && existingStudent.LastName == Student.LastName) {
        class.Students.Add(existingStudent);
      } else {
        throw new HttpException(409, string.Format("A student with the email address {0} already exists. " +
                            "However, the first and/or last name you entered is does not match the user in the system. " +
                            "\nYou entered: {1} {2}.\nOur system shows {3} {4}.\nHit OK to add the student in " +
                            "the system to this class. If not, hit Cancel then enter another email address.", 
                            Student.Email, Student.FirstName, Student.LastName, existingStudent.FirstName, existingStudent.LastName));

      }
    }

    class.Students.Add(Student);

    db.SaveChanges();

  }
}
```

**AngularJS**

I want SweetAlert (swal) to be shown dependent on the error. Obviously if the error is a student already existing WITHIN a class, an OK button is all that is needed. But if it is a student being added to another class that is already in the database (with a different/misspelled name but same email), SweetAlert should show a Cancel button and a button to Confirm addition of student to the other class. Also if I think of other possible errors, I'd like SweetAlert to be able to show the correct buttons (confirming, closing, etc) as needed.

```
$scope.addStudent = function(class) {
 if ($scope.studentFirstName && $scope.studentLastName && $scope.studentEmail) {
    MembersService.addStudent(
      Student = {
        FirstName: $scope.studentFirstName,
        LastName: $scope.studentLastName,
        Email: $scope.studentEmail,
      })
    .success(function() {
      swal("Student added!", "", "success")
      MembersService.getClasses()
        .success(function(classes) {
          $scope.classes = classes.data.Classes;
        })
      MembersService.getClassStudents(class.ClassId)
        .success(function(classStudents) {
          $scope.classStudents = classStudents.data.ClassStudents
      })
      //empty input values
      $scope.studentFirstName = "";
      $scope.studentLastName = "";
      $scope.studentEmail = "";
    })
    .error(function(xhr, status, error) {
      //this should be dependent on the error.
      swal({
        title: 'Uh Oh!',
        text: xhr.message,
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnConfirm: false,
      }, function() {
          //Add student in the system to class
      }
    })
}
else {
    //empty values...
  }
}
```

Maybe throwing an exception is not the best way to do it. Any suggestions? I'm kind of stuck on the best approach at this point. I might just need a custom error handler to pass another object to track various errors then return those errors accordingly. But any better suggestions will be great!

Comment: [Avoid using exceptions for program flow](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why)

Comment: It's hard to see why you catch an exception and return the code and message instead of just letting it bubble up.